# Finding $z$ such that $\Re(\frac{z}{-3+2i}) = \frac{10}{13},\;|3-2\overline{z}| = |2z+3i|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I wish to find $z$ such that $\displaystyle \Re(\frac{z}{-3+2i}) = \frac{10}{13},\;|3-2\overline{z}| = |2z+3i|$.

We may simplify $\displaystyle \frac{z}{-3+2i} = \frac{x+iy}{-3+2i} \frac{-3-2i}{-3-2i} = \frac{-3x+2y + i(-2x+3y)}{13}$.

Taking the real part of the fraction above gives us $\displaystyle \frac{-3x+2y}{13}$

Then, $-3x+2y = 10$

So now we move onto the other equation.

Recall that $|z|=z\overline{z}$ and $z=x+iy$. Then, $|3-2(x-iy)| = |2(x+iy)+3i|$, $|3-2x+2iy| = |2x+2iy+3i|$,

Then, $$(3-2x+2iy)(3-2x-2iy) = (2x+i(3+2y))(2x-i(3+2y))$$

which simplifies to $$4x^2-12x+4y^2+9 = 4x^2 - i(2y+3)^2$$.

But this is still messy and does not simplify further. Can anyone see where I messed up?

Comment: Notice that $z=x+iy$ implies $$\frac{x+iy}{-3+2i}\frac{-3-2i}{-3-2i}=\frac{-3x+2y+i(-2x-3y)}{13}$$

Comment: There is an additional $i$ in the right-hand side in the last line. I just want to comment, since I think you made a good first post, showing your calculations. Welcome to Math.SE!

Comment: Mario is also right, but has no impact on result

Comment: $|z|^2=z\overline{z}$, you omitted the 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $$|3-2\bar{z}| = |2z+3i|\Rightarrow |(2\bar{z}-3)| = |2z+3i|\;,$$ Now put $$z=x+iy$$

We get $$\displaystyle |(2x-3)+i(2y)| = |2x+i(2y+3)|\Rightarrow (2x-3)^2+4y^2=(2x)^2+(2y+3)^2$$

So we get $$\displaystyle 9-12x = 9+12y\Rightarrow x+y=0.....(1)$$

and First part $$\displaystyle \bf{\Re\left(\frac{z}{-3+2i}\right)} = \frac{10}{13},$$ You have got $$-3x+2y=10..............(2)$$

so we get $$\displaystyle x=-2,y=2$$, So we get $$z=x+iy=-2+2i$$

Comment: Why do you say we have $\frac{10}{3}$?

Comment: I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

again see last line $4x^2-12x+4y^2+9 = 4x^2 - i(2y+3)^2$, you have to wright
$4x^2-12x+4y^2+9 = 4x^2 +(2y+3)^2$

I sugesst you use complex modulus it will help you to reach answer in short way. $|z_1|=|z_2|$the $x_{2}^{2}+y_{2}^{2}=|z_1|^2=|z_2|^2=x_{1}^{2}+y_{1}^{2}$